# Fully disable Qt main window including menu bar?

Tags: qt, qt5, qmainwindow, qt5.3, qt5.4

I need to temporarily disable the main window, including the menu bar. The main window can be disabled simply using `setEnabled(false)` however it seems that doesn't disable the menu bar, so the user can still click menu items (which in my case break the application).

Is there any way to completely disable all user interactions, including the menu bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `setEnabled(false)` in main window also disables menu bar. Any way you can also use `setEnabled` method of `QMenuBar` class :

```
ui->menuBar->setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Hmm... calling `menuBar()->setEnabled(false)` removes the menu bar, however calling `setEnabled(true)` doesn't bring it back. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: No. When I call `menuBar()->setEnabled(false)` it gets just disabled. That's weird.

Answer (score 1):

You should set parent of the menu bar. It should be main window. If parent disabled, actions will be disabled too.